# Setting up QOS-dependent preemption on slurm

Tags: slurm

I'm using a SLURM cluster that is supposed to be set up to allow for QOS-based preemption, but I'm not sure if it's been done correctly. Is it correct to say that for this to work, each QOS that we want to preempt another must explicitly list those which it can preempt? In other words, if I run `$ sacctmgr list qos format==name,priority,preempt` and the "preempt" column is empty, we effectively do *not* have QOS-based preemption enabled, regardless of the fact that `PreemptType = preempt/qos`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right. For instance in our setup:

```
[root@master ~]# sacctmgr list qos format==name,priority,preempt
      Name   Priority    Preempt
---------- ---------- ----------
    normal          0
      high      10000     normal
```

and jobs with QOS `high` are able to preempt jobs with QOS `normal`.  This situation was obtained by running a command such as:

```
sacctmgr modify qos where name=high set Preempt=normal
```